# Update libraries to support AndroidX

Tags: android-support-library, androidx

Currently I am updating my project to support AndroidX.
I've refactored all libraries to the new `androidx`- ones.
Still, there are dependencies, as, for example, `com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker`, that won't be updated and are displayed in a way that looks very ugly in the UI.

[image]

How can I force these buttons to use the new material libraries?
I've enabled the options

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

but it won't affect these libraries, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be simple as that:

> Material Components replaces all instances of Button with an instance
>   of MaterialButton when using one of its regular themes:
>   https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes
>   The default version of MaterialButton uses colorPrimary as the
>   background color. Because Material Components replaces the View
>   replacer with their own implementation there is not much I can do to
>   fix this from this library.
>
> There are two workarounds:
>
> Use one of the bridge themes, which do not replace the View Inflater
>   Overwrite the View inflater again in your application theme by adding
>   the following statement in your application theme: androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater
>   You will then need to explicitly use MaterialButton in your
>   application rather than Button

So what you basically have to do, is to add the line to your Application Theme. Then, Material Components won't be replaced anymore. Voila!

```
<item> name="viewInflaterClass">androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater</item>
```

Referring to https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker